# Session Callback Customization Fails to Save Access Token in Local Storage on Production

Tags: next.js, next-auth

#### Description

I've implemented custom session callback logic in my Next.js application to include an access token within the session object. This setup works as expected in my local development environment, where the access token is properly included in the session object and stored in local storage. However, when deployed to a production environment on Heroku, the access token is missing from the session object, and local storage remains empty.

#### Expected Behavior

The expected behavior is for the session object to include the access token and for the access token to be available in local storage, similar to how it functions in the local development environment.

#### Current Behavior

In the production environment, the session object does not include the access token, and local storage related to the session is completely empty.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Configure next-auth with custom session and JWT callbacks to include an access token in the session.
2. Implement a page that utilizes the access token from the session to make additional requests.
3. Observe the expected behavior in the local development environment.
4. Deploy the application to Heroku and observe the missing access token and empty local storage in the production environment.

**Code Snippets**

**- NextAuth Config**

```js
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials || !credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          console.error("Insufficient credentials provided");
          return null;
        }
        try {
          const res = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/auth/token`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Accept: "application/json"
              },
              body: new URLSearchParams({
                username: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password
              })
            }
          );

          const data = await res.json();
          if (!res.ok) {
            return null;
          }

          const accessToken = data.access_token;

          const res2 = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/v1/auth/me`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
          });

          const userData = await res2.json();
          if (!res2.ok) {
            return null;
          }

          const isAdmin = userData?.is_admin;
          if (!isAdmin) {
            console.error("User is not an admin");
            return null;
          }

          return {
            id: userData.id,
            full_name: userData.full_name,
            email: userData.email,
            access_token: accessToken
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return null;
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.full_name = user.full_name;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.access_token = user.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = {
        ...session.user,
        id: token.id as string | undefined,
        name: token.full_name as string | undefined,
        email: token.email as string | undefined
      };
      session.accessToken = token.access_token as string | undefined;
      return session;
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/"
  }
};
```

**- Custom Types (`next-auth.d.ts`):**

```js
import "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id?: string;
      name?: string;
      email?: string;
    } & Partial<User>;
    accessToken?: string;
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  interface JWT {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    email?: string;
    accessToken?: string;
  }

  interface User {
    id?: string;
    full_name?: string;
    email?: string;
    access_token?: string;
  }
}
```

**- Page usage of session example**

```js
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getSession, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import BreadCrumb from '@/components/breadcrumb'
import { UserClient } from '@/components/tables/user-tables/client'
import { getAllUsers } from '@/services/users'
import { User } from '@/types/user'

const breadcrumbItems = [{ title: 'User', link: '/dashboard/user' }]

export default function Page() {
 const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
 const { data: session, status, update } = useSession()
 console.log(session)

 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchUsers = async () => {
     if (session && session.accessToken) {
       const token = session.accessToken
       try {
         const fetchedUsers = await getAllUsers(token)
         setUsers(fetchedUsers)
       } catch (error) {
         console.error('Failed to fetch users:', error)
       }
     }
   }

   fetchUsers()
 }, [session])

 return (
   <>
     <div className="flex-1 space-y-4 p-4 md:p-8 pt-6">
       <BreadCrumb items={breadcrumbItems} />
       <UserClient data={users} />
     </div>
   </>
 )
}
```

**Detailed Logs**

**Local Environment Log (Working as Expected)**

```json
{
    "user": {
        "name": "joão",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "id": 6
    },
    "expires": "2024-03-24T21:39:56.719Z",
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyX2lkOjYiLCJleHAiOjE3MDg3Mjc5ODh9.Dac4_CQ66pp48VnF_1F9zx7z2lKbL0JP8EBq2Dei15s"
}
```

**Production Environment Log (Issue Occurring)**

```json
{
    "user": {
        "name": "joão",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "id": 6
    },
    "expires": "2024-03-24T21:39:56.719Z"
}
```

**Local Storage Content in Local Environment**

```json
{
    "event": "session",
    "data": {
        "trigger": "getSession"
    },
    "timestamp": 1708724425
}
```

**Local Storage in Production Environment**

- The local storage is totally empty, indicating that the access token is not being stored as expected.

**Additional Context**

- This setup works flawlessly in a local environment.
- All environment variables are correctly set in the production environment on Heroku.
- The log of the session in the local environment includes the access token, but in the production environment, it does not.

**Environment**

- Next.js version: 14.0.1
- NextAuth version: 4.24.4
- Deployment platform: Heroku

#### Expected Behavior

The expected behavior is for the session object to include the access token and for the access token to be available in local storage, similar to how it functions in the local development environment.